# Wixsharp External UI (WPF) Installation Path

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-installer, wixsharp

I've been working on external UI for my installer, generated with WixSharp.
WixSharp samples library has a quite good example on how to create WPF external UI, but I don't understand, how to prompt user to change installation path of my application. Obviously, I have a Setup class, derived from GenericSetup andI can pass a parameter to my MSI file when calling `base.StartInstall()` method. But how can I get installation directory ftom my MSI to show it for user in a first place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's actually quite simple. MSI is a database by it's nature, and we can read it. WixSharp provides neat `MsiParser` class, that can read some of the properties, stored in MSI.
It can be used in such way:

```
var msi = new MsiParser(MsiFile);
var dir = msi.GetDirectoryPath("INSTALLDIR");
```

This question was originally answered by Oleg Shilo on [github issue thread](https://github.com/oleg-shilo/wixsharp/issues/412)